# Why does NetBeans highlight text between '<' and '>' in C comments

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.2 as my C-code editor. Any text inside C-comments between '<' and '>' characters is highlighted (see image below). Does anyone know why?

There is no highlighting in my C-code; it only happens in the comment sections.

[image: NetBeans highlighting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetBeans highlights text between <> symbols because it interprets it as a `doxygen` formatting. See [doxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/doxygen/info) tag info.

For example:

[image]